# XML a CSV con subelementos en los tags

Tags: python, xml, csv

Estoy tratando de convertor un archivo xls a csv pero tengo problemas porque el archivo xml tiene subelementos que se cumplen para algunos tags y no para otros.
Este es el xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="Employee.xsl"?>
<Employees>
<Employee>
    <name>Rajesh</name>
    <address>Chennai</address>
    <transferencia>
        <transferencia_envio>
          <entidades_participantes_envio>
            <nombre_participante_envio>
              <nombre_corresponsal>0aa73494e622f8ac3c359475bf7307b8571074d4e5c3606ad569403a70eef0d6</nombre_corresponsal>
            </nombre_participante_envio>
          </entidades_participantes_envio>
          <bic_aba>CHASUS33XXX</bic_aba>
          <datos_destinatario>6e6c48a74bad3daa313862b15a8c655269890d98cf96e4ee860a5f05ec632331</datos_destinatario>
          <operacion_origen>USD 11295.47</operacion_origen>
          <operacion_destino>USD 11295.47</operacion_destino>
          <instrumentos_origen>
            <instrumento_origen>
              <instrumento_monetario_origen>02</instrumento_monetario_origen>
              <moneda_origen>USD</moneda_origen>
              <monto_instrumento_origen>11295.47</monto_instrumento_origen>
            </instrumento_origen>
          </instrumentos_origen>
          <memo_envio>
            <mensaje>SIN MENSAJE</mensaje>
</memo_envio>
        </transferencia_envio>
      </transferencia>
      <persona>
        <tipo_persona>
          <persona_moral>
            <razon_social>875c0b0b0db6d3a3db9ad1fea0691d9ca94a05ab7550081a8b6dcd6b4fe97f80</razon_social>
            <fecha_constitucion>19951012</fecha_constitucion>
            <pais_nacionalidad>MX</pais_nacionalidad>
            <giro_mercantil>3999101</giro_mercantil>
            <apoderado_legal>8da45f8ccca6b4bd37e6e10b0cf18466023eec7ae3e43cf3521d9063dd477a14</apoderado_legal>
          </persona_moral>
        </tipo_persona>
        <domicilio>
          <nacional>
            <tipo_domicilio>
              <unificado>
                <domicilio_unificado>ef679d17e21882d6e026971779128fe52b7229e907f96edcd1d81d0113d4dde1</domicilio_unificado>
                <ciudad_poblacion>403379ba610e8596ba42dc869fdfdd17db8ede7dd323952654115c102d21d08b</ciudad_poblacion>
                <codigo_postal>7e33c11cc6c42be392435817f8713ae213596efc7244f2272aa7f93377e044de</codigo_postal>
              </unificado>
            </tipo_domicilio>
          </nacional>
        </domicilio>
        <telefono>
          <numero_telefono>5c1dba9c14beed8d69fccb07529f4c39fc0ce834aeffc62373348177ea17b1af</numero_telefono>
          <clave_pais>MX</clave_pais>
        </telefono>
      </persona>
    </Employee>
<Employee>
    <name>Suresh</name>
    <address>Chennai</address>
          <transferencia>
        <transferencia_recepcion>
          <bic_aba>COBADEFFXXX</bic_aba>
          <datos_ordenante>2a87dcae5c709866850a0ed3b5198a2dc2f5128292de6f393a69a6b0218cb055</datos_ordenante>
          <operacion_origen>EUR 1000.00</operacion_origen>
          <instrumentos_destino>
            <instrumento_destino>
              <instrumento_monetario_destino>02</instrumento_monetario_destino>
              <moneda_destino>MXN</moneda_destino>
              <monto_instrumento_destino>20650.00</monto_instrumento_destino>
            </instrumento_destino>
          </instrumentos_destino>
        </transferencia_recepcion>
      </transferencia>
      <persona>
        <tipo_persona>
          <persona_moral>
            <razon_social>25680448f4f74126280e51ff47e68119169073b443ee170855913c54e3dac710</razon_social>
            <fecha_constitucion>20001026</fecha_constitucion>
            <pais_nacionalidad>MX</pais_nacionalidad>
            <giro_mercantil>8412017</giro_mercantil>
            <apoderado_legal>e8f355427fdf90d50502e88cdff211f9644a2448a80511f3c581e5b8b2508c6e</apoderado_legal>
          </persona_moral>
        </tipo_persona>
        <domicilio>
          <nacional>
            <tipo_domicilio>
              <unificado>
                <domicilio_unificado>57e193adc745b7c941ab320ac2a58eeb88d5902fb8255b9b5bbe96837e93846e</domicilio_unificado>
                <ciudad_poblacion>9cffe11a7599ccda2fb40ac2fcbf746471e57d7ccb8aafc5bac7a31da69784bc</ciudad_poblacion>
                <codigo_postal>a58c58e831248f3be7aa49a0a734221bcd184ba4cfb037be866e6efba99a152b</codigo_postal>
              </unificado>
            </tipo_domicilio>
          </nacional>
        </domicilio>
        <telefono>
          <numero_telefono>375bff161771ab3f045a677de5dabd6a5e7223fc730be6a2569220b3f06af530</numero_telefono>
          <clave_pais>MX</clave_pais>
        </telefono>
      </persona>
    </Employee>
</Employees>
```

En Office se ve así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Quiero que así sea mi salida de csv, con celdas vacías donde no se tienen los mismos elementos.

Mi código va así.

```
import  csv
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('FTI.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
xml_data_to_csv =open('Out1.csv','w')

csvwriter = csv.writer(xml_data_to_csv, delimiter=',')

count = 0



head = ['name','adress','nombre_corresponsal','bic_aba','datos_destinatario','operacion_origen','operacion_destino','instrumento_monetario_origen','moneda_origen','monto_instrumento_origen','mensaje','bic_aba','datos_ordenante','operacion_origen','instrumento_monetario_destino','moneda_destino','monto_instrumento_destino','nombre_corresponsal','razon_social','fecha_constitucion','pais_nacionalidad','giro_mercantil','apoderado_legal','nombre','apellido_paterno','apellido_materno','fecha_nacimiento','pais_nacimiento','pais_nacionalidad','actividad_economica','domicilio_unificado','ciudad_poblacion','codigo_postal','numero_telefono','clave_pais']
operacion = root[0]
trans = operacion[3]
csvwriter.writerow(head)
for element in root.findall('operacion'):
    row = []
    folio_consecutivo = element.find('folio_consecutivo').text
    row.append(folio_consecutivo)
    fecha = element.find('fecha').text
    row.append(fecha)
    referencia = element.find('referencia').text
    row.append(referencia)
    #categ = time.find('categories').find('tree').find('entry').text
    #row.append(categ)
    csvwriter.writerow(row)
    count = +1
xml_data_to_csv.close()
```

Agradezco cualquier sugerencia

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! En que lenguaje?

Comment: Es en Python. Gracias.